# "И наклейка на боку — / Надпись: "В собственном соку"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Собственно, когда мы рассказывает о составе сока, то говорим: "В этом сокЕ содержится много витаминов", но при этом — ананасы в собственном сокУ. Почему так? Или "в собственном соку" — это сложившийся торговый термин?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Словарь трудностей говорит:
СОК - предл. в соке и допустимо в соку. В устойчивых сочетаниях: в самом (полном) соку (в расцвете сил), вариться в собственном соку, в желудочном соке.

Т.е. в соку-остаток местного падежа,устаревшая норма, сейчас возможно использование его в качестве разговорного варианта и в устойчивых выражениях, норма - в соке.